# How to set IFRAME's background color to the BG-color of it's parent document?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, joomla

I am working on a Joomla 1.5 website and a little self-contained php application, which I want to show within an IFRAME inserted in an article. The template I am using for the website has a dark grey background and the IFRAME shows grey background when loaded in Firefox (I don't quite know *why* this is so, but I like it like this). However, when the page is loaded in IE, the IFRAME has white background (understandably).

How can I make the IFRAME copy the background color of its parent document also in IE?

---

Also, I have another unanswered [question related to IFRAME usage and Joomla 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514488/iframes-and-wysiwyg-editor-in-joomla-1-5), which I would like to point your attention to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the self-contained application is on the same domain as the article page, you could access the top frame (with the article) through javascript - like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(window.top.document.body);
```

Computed style can be get as described in [this article](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/).

Your other option is to add a query string parameter for the iframe, like `bgcolor=` - this is a more widget-like approach, and will make the stand-alone application more configurable. I personally recommend this approach - it will not rely on javascript and it will not flicker if the execution gets slow.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Yes, the application is on the same domain and I will try the javascript solution, although I see why the second option has your preference.

Comment: first option won't work on IE, which uses currentStyle instead, and older browsers where neither is available. It also relies on the background being set on the body tag only; if it were set on the html tag or any other div inside the body it'd not work. The `bgcolor` parameter, on the other hand, is explicit and solid.

Comment: @bobince good point about the body tag - the currentStyle/computedStyle difference is explained in the article - I just used the term to describe the concept...